# Exclude time range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In fact I have a table to store the details of calls and I need to filter the calls which entered the IVR after 16:00:00 till 06:59:00 the next day for **ENTIRE MONTH** I have used *BETWEEN* clause but it includes the details of all times of the month.

```
SELECT 
    [conversationId],
    [conversationStart]
FROM 
    [Customer].[dbo].[vw_Conversations]
WHERE 
    conversationStart BETWEEN '2018-01-01 16:00:00.000' AND '2018-01-31 06:59:59.000'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It won't be fast, but one method would be to use `CONVERT`/`CAST` and convert the datetime to a time. Then use the `>=` and `<` operators. `BETWEEN` is probably not your friend here (at least for getting the values between the certain times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DATEPART()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) function to test hour of the day. In your case, checking hours is enough:

```
SELECT conversationId,
       conversationStart
  FROM [Customer].[dbo].[vw_Conversations]
  WHERE conversationStart BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01'
    AND DATEPART(hour, conversationStart) NOT BETWEEN 7 AND 15
```

Comment: @HusseinALSHAMIRI – thank you for the feedback. If this was the most helpful answer, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to just test the time component.  I am not sure what date range you want, but the query is something like this:

```
SELECT conversationId, conversationStart
FROM Customer.dbo.[w_Conversations c
WHERE CONVERT(date, conversationStart) >= '2018-01-01' AND
      CONVERT(date, conversationStart) < '2018-02-01' AND
      (CONVERT(time, conversationStart) >= '16:00:00') OR
       CONVERT(time, conversationStart) < '07:00:00')
      );
```